# Create a new price attribute for the product

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, price

I want to add a price attribute for my product.

So I can add this to my product as a decimal attribute but...I don't know how to give him the options in order that this attribute comes out with the same render as existing price in the product form. Tried to investigate the magento catalog and the magento wee tax but I didn't found anything very understandable.

I want to come out with that result: any idea ?

[image: price]

Answer (score 0):

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'price_kg',
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'type' => 'decimal',
                'backend' => Price::class,
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Prix au Kg',
                'input' => 'price',
                'class' => '',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

Not exactly the same rendering though but it works